# Rails - get all possible values in a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a very simple data model, as follows:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :object_tags
has_many :tags, through: :object_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :object_tags
has_many :objects, through: :object_tags
end

class ObjectTag < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :object
belongs_to :tag 
end
```

Both Object and Tag have a name attribute.

What I want to do is, for a defined set of objects @objects, get an array of all the possible tags names that my set of objects can take. I would like to be able to do something like that (which is wrong, but just for illustration purpose) : `@objects.pluck(:tags.name).uniq`

I have tried quite a lot of things, with includes and joins, but nothing gets me to my result. The closest I got was `@objects.includes(:tags).pluck(:tags)`, but it only gets my the array of tags, then I can't retrieve the name.
This might be a very straightforward question, but I am a beginner in Rails and could not find anything in my research.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: [`Object` it's a bad name for your model.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html) Object is the default root of all Ruby objects.

Comment: Try `@objects.collect(&:tags)`

Comment: I got it working with `@object.includes(:tags).uniq.map{ |tag| tag.name }`. Does that sound like a reasonable solution?

Comment: @Alexandre, `@object` or `@objects` ?

Comment: and what does it return `@objects.collect(&:tags).flatten` ?

Comment: @objects sorry: `@object.includes(:tags).uniq.map{ |tag| tag.name }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
@object.tags.uniq.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this, I get "undefined method `tags' for #<Class:xxx>"

Comment: @Alexandre: what is `@objects` exactly(it seems that you should have association `tags` in `Object` model, so I'm referring to it)?

Comment: It is a set of objects that is defined in my controller, which depends on the User who is logged in. If that makes things less clear, we can work with Object directly

Comment: Let's assume `@objects = Object.all` (which is sometimes true)